# Mybatis loop with AND

Tags: sql, mybatis

I have a sql query of this kind of structure:

```
......
......
where a.id=#{x} AND b.id!=#{x}
......
```

Now I want to change this query to accept a list of values of x. How should I write foreach loop for this?

Answer (score 3):

I would change your WHERE to the form

 `SELECT ... FROM ...  WHERE a.id IN (...x...) AND b.id NOT IN (...x...)`

Then, your annotation or XML would contain:

```
  SELECT ...
  FROM ...
  WHERE a.id IN <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="x"
        open="(" separator="," close=")">
          #{item}
    </foreach>
  AND b.id NOT IN <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="x"
        open="(" separator="," close=")">
          #{item}
    </foreach>
```

This will produce more efficient SQL.